# How do I run MATLAB (.m) files in VSCode?

Tags: matlab, visual-studio-code

I am not able to figure out how to run MATLAB (.m) code in VSCode.

I have installed the [MATLAB Extension for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gimly81.matlab) and added the path for the `mlint` file for MATLAB as stated in the extension.

```
"matlab.mlintpath"
```

VSCode identifies the file as a MATLAB file. However, the code won't run.

How can I run MATLAB code from within VSCode?

Comment: Do you mean "run" as in execute the code? As MATLAB is proprietary, there are only two ways to run MATLAB code: by running the code from the MATLAB IDE (with a valid license of course), or by compiling it to an executable file with the MATLAB compiler.

Comment: Yes I do mean to execute the code. So is there no way that I can directly execute the code from a vscode command prompt?

Comment: You could, provided you have a working installation of MATLAB on your computer and call that from a command line, or use one of the workarounds mentioned in my answer. Without having access to a valid license and working installation of MATLAB you cannot run the code, which is by design.

Comment: On Windows you cannot start a Matlab session inside the terminal, there will be always an interactive Matlab console popping up (like `matlab -nodesktop -nosplash <fileToRun.m>`). I wrote a guide that allows you to execute sections/lines/complete files in a running Matlab IDE from vscode, [link](https://github.com/rick3rt/vscode-run-matlab). It's a bit hacky, but allows me to enjoy e.g. the multiline editing of vscode and then quickly run code sections by pressing a keyboard shortcut instead of switching to matlab, and run the entire file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of April 2023 the below is no longer the only way to run MATLAB from VSCode. See [the answer by svenmk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76117724/5211833) about [the plugin by The MathWorks themselves](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MathWorks.language-matlab&ssr=false).

---

There is a way, [this VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bramvanbilsen.matlab-code-run) suggests that you can use it to run MATLAB code from within VSCode without having to open the MATLAB GUI. It does not invalidate the below though; you need to have a working, licensed MATLAB installation, which will be called in the background. Without a working, licensed MATLAB installation you cannot run MATLAB code.

---

As MATLAB is proprietary, there are only two ways to run MATLAB code: by running the code from the MATLAB IDE (with a valid license of course), or by compiling it to an executable file with the [MATLAB compiler](https://mathworks.com/products/compiler.html).
You might be able to get other IDEs to have syntax highlighting and typing-hints like MATLAB's own IDE through importing its `mlint` functionality, like you did, but that won't execute the code.

Thus no, you cannot execute MATLAB code directly within VSCode, you can only covertly call the MATLAB engine from inside VSCode.

---

A possible workaround would be to export your MATLAB code to C/C++ using the [MATLAB Coder](https://mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder.html). You can then run the C/C++ code from within VSCode.

Comment: You can also invoke MATLAB code from outside of the IDE (I imagine this is possible with some VSCode extensions) but your main point stands, you need MATLAB installed to do this, and it will be calling the MATLAB engine implicitly.

Comment: This extension works for me. It should be noted that the Matlab executable needs to be the user's path. I think the first sentence alone would be a excellent answer to the question, and am puzzled why there is a long discourse on the nature of Matlab's license and how to generate C. It is in fact possible to run Matlab without the IDE, `matlab -nosplash -nodesktop` which I use routinely from the shell, and that is what this extension uses.

Comment: @Liam the long discourse is necessary, because having the extension without a valid MATLAB license+installation won't work.The Coder and `mlint` parts are less relevant, granted, and were added to clarify other options (especially given that the OP mentions installing `mlint` in the question).

Answer (score 4):

Yesterday MathWorks has released its own [VSCode plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MathWorks.language-matlab&ssr=false)

It does not seem to support execution / debugging by now, but I think it is worth keeping an eye on since it already sets up some background connection to your local MATLAB-installation and [execution is planned to be added in the future](https://github.com/mathworks/MATLAB-extension-for-vscode/issues/4#issuecomment-1524803299).

Comment: So I can work in vs-code but I can not run the code there?

Comment: Up to now, yes. But linting is already working.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the term linting, what is this ?

Comment: Linting is a static analysis of code quality, helping to identify possible sources of error. Wikipedia explains it much better than I can: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR:

I wrote Matlab Terminal Extension for VS Code on Linux. It can run MATLAB files and spawn a MATLAB -Terminal. You can find the repo [here](https://github.com/mauzigoe/matter-for-vscode). Note that this still requires you to have a valid MATLAB license installed.

## MatTer for VS Code

I recently wanted to used a MATLAB  terminal in VSCode. There even is an extension for this. But while using the extension I faced some flaws. Also the repository does not seem to be active anymore and the owner doesn't react to issues and similar.

So I decided to write my own first extension *MatTer for VS Code* and published it to the VS marketplace. It's in early Development, but it can already spawn a MATLAB -Terminal and run MATLAB  files.

The repo is hosted on Github, see here: https://github.com/mauzigoe/matter-for-vscode

To install it via VSCode just search for *matter-for-vscode* in *Extension*.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the "Matlab Interactive Terminal" Extention, the link is below.
To use it, you need to follow the instruction to install a "MATLAB Engine API for Python" and you are good to go (and you need a working Matlab).

after installing the extension, you could open the Matlab terminal in the command window (by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P and input "Open a Matlab Terminal"), and you could get the same Matlab terminal as in the real Matlab IDE, and now you could run .m code in Vscode.

Comment: This is the best method. I also suggest adding the following to your keybindings.json file. For regular use, one might also want to assign a keybinding to the "Open a Matlab Terminal" command. The code-runner method works too but is slower to launch than the matlab-interactive-terminal extension method which uses the matlab engine api for python.   {
  "key": "shift+enter",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'matlab'"
 }

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Code Runner extension and put this line in your `settings.json`:

```json
"code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension": {
    ".m": "cd $dir && matlab -batch \"$fileNameWithoutExt\""
}
```

You would probably also want to install the MATLAB extension.

Answer (score 0):

"@Liam the long discourse is necessary, because having the extension without a valid MATLAB license+installation won't work.T"

...because at some point you need at least ONE working matlab install just to develop the m-file :)

I suspect that you're right, and it comes down to a choice between embedding "foreign" code into an m-file, or making calls to the matlab engine from within a foreign IDE. They do have a free RTE but you still need some form of Matlab IDE to write in plus the Matlab Compiler toolbox to build the project out for the RTE.

The work-around is to use OS tools to remove Matlab and other proprietary tools from the loop entirely. That is why if you're going to be forced to pay $5k for a proprietary tool, it has to be justified in other ways than "it can get the job done".

VS Code extensions have the same problem as any other extension: if you look at the repository and see what is required to install and run the extension? You'll probably never install an extension again. It's about as wise as blithely downloading and installing any code from the Internet: it's no better than the source. I would wait until you figure-out how to call getOpen() etc within VS Code without downloading some random extension from some random source especially one that hasn't been updated in the past 2 years.  Or at least use VS2019 Community:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100603-how-can-i-compile-a-matlab-engine-application-using-microsoft-visual-studio-9-0-or-10-0

Answer (score 0):

Install octave compiler, cd to the respective directory and just run "octave " from command line...
e.g. :
abhibratanandy@fedora ~/A/Matlab (master)> octave first.m
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread
qt.qpa.qgnomeplatform.theme: The desktop style for QtQuick Controls 2 applications is not available on the system (qqc2-desktop-style). The application may look broken.

a * b =
455   544   633
456   600   744
x =

1   2   3

ans =

-1.0000 + 1.4142i
-1.0000 - 1.4142i

b =

```
1   -6   11   -6
```

c =

```
 1     0   -97  -300   396
```

a =

2   3   5

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, just now you can't run the code directly from vs code. you can follow this way:

First: install the extension of Matlab in vs code.

Second: you can edit your code from vs code by new formatting and run the code in Matlab, so at the same time edit the file from vs code and run it in Matlab editor.

Answer (score 0):

MathWorks' [MATLAB extension for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/mathworks/MATLAB-extension-for-vscode) now supports running MATLAB code in VS Code (version 1.2, available since 05 March 2024). It still has some limitations, e.g. debugging MATLAB code inside VS Code is not (yet) supported.

See https://github.com/mathworks/MATLAB-extension-for-vscode?tab=readme-ov-file#run-matlab-code for instructions and limitations.