# Color parentheses groups in MATLAB's IDE

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to make Matlab color matching parentheses?

```
A = max(B(:,3))
```

where the function parentheses for `max()` should have the same color, as well as the indexing parentheses `B(:,3)` having a different one.

Comment: You mean in the IDE, right? I don't think so, no. I guess one thing you could try is to program in Visual Studio Code or something like that, and see if the MATLAB plugins do it. You can always then just run the program via command line, but you lose the workspace variable editor and other nice features.

Comment: Yea, I mean the IDE. What you describes seems like a cure worse than the disease situation. I might copy paste the code to an empty editor to identify the problems though.

I just wish matlab had this feature. Honestly, if a single IDE in the world supported nested parantheses coloring, it should probably be matlab, one would think.

Comment: 100% agree. But it doesn't. I mean, it doesn't even have a dark theme by default, you need to get a FEX hack that looks ugly to make it dark. They need some work on that...

Comment: Or you create a MATLAB GUI that mimics all the functionalities of MATLAB's IDE plus does what you want. Seems tedious though

Comment: You can import MATLAB's [`mlint`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mlint.html) functionality, that which does code markdown, into other IDEs, e.g. [VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64279258/5211833). You might be able to edit the `mlint` file to do what you want.

Comment: Honestly, if you have so many parentheses that you can’t tell them apart, you need to split your code up more. Define some intermediate variables for subexpressions. You need to keep your code simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well this is not a full answer to the question, but it made me change one of my settings, so for what it's worth:

By default in MATLAB editor when you click on a parenthesis, an underscore appears under this parenthesis and the matching one. This can be changed in the settings so that instead of having an underscore, your matching parenthesis will be highlighted, which I find clearer:

[image: Preferences]

Select "Highlight" for the "Match on arrow key" option.

It's gonna look like that:

[image: demo]

Comment: Wow, thanks. At least now I wont have to activate laser vision to catch the fleeting moment when the underscore is visible.

Comment: Annoyingly, this menu is absent in 2021b version of matlab.

Comment: can you trying typing these: `s=settings; s.matlab.keyboard.delimiter`. What does MATLAB output?

Comment: @GappyHilmore It's a bit weird that you can't find it, It's there on both 2021a and 2022a

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/mGJYDBb.png this is what I have on one of my machines.

Comment: @GappyHilmore What about the commands outputs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245471/discussion-between-gappy-hilmore-and-billbokeey).

Comment: Probably closest matlab will ever get to having colored parentheses. Ironically, they have since removed this feature. I guess I can rest easy knowing matlab offers no such ability.